# Spring Integration WebFlux inboundGateway replyChannel for error response

Tags: spring-integration

Trying to use the `replyChannel` for sending an error response for the `WebFlux.inboundGateway`, however no response is sent from ErrorFlow and the client continues to wait for response. Kindly suggest.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/some/uri")
                                    .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(POST))
                                    .requestPayloadType(SomeObject.class)
                                    .replyChannel(webReplyChannel)
                                    .errorChannel(appErrorChannel))


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow appErrorFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())
                        .<ErrorMessage, Message<String>> transform(errorMessage -> MessageBuilder.withPayload("Error Response")
                                                                                        .copyHeaders(((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                                                                                        .build())
                        .get();
```

**Exception:**

```
2023-01-14 13:34:10,343 [reactor-http-nio-2        ] ERROR o.s.i.h.LambdaMessageProcessor - 1283c6fd42485bf5 Could not invoke the method 'public java.lang.Object com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx..ErrorFlowConfig$$Lambda$2129/0x0000000801ac3a00.transform(java.lang.Object)' due to a class cast exception, if using a lambda in the DSL, consider using an overloaded EIP method that takes a Class<?> argument to explicitly  specify the type. An example of when this often occurs is if the lambda is configured to receive a Message<?> argument.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.xxxxxxx.model.dto.SomeObject cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage (com.xxxxxxx.model.dto.SomeObject is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @32f93dff; org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:115)
    at o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known framework limitation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3984.

So, for now you have to do like this instead:

```
.transform(Message.class,
           errorMessage -> 
                       MessageBuilder.withPayload("Error Response")
                                .copyHeaders(((MessagingException) errorMessage.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                                .build())
```

Only those `getFailedMessage().getHeaders()` contain respective `replyChannel` and `errorChannel` headers.

Comment: Please see my update, ran into `ClassCastException`, it is weird how the WebFlux request payload is referred as the message payload instead of `MessagingException` or `ErrorMessage`

Comment: So, that exception gives you a hint to use an overloaded method where you specify a first arg as `Message.class`. That's first.

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes tried those already and it works ONLY IF cloud-sleuth is NOT added as a dependency. Else `java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.integration.sample.model.dto.SomeObject cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException`. Please see this https://github.com/syedyusufh/webflux-inboundgateway-error sample project reproducing the same issue, it works as expected if cloud-sleuth dependency is removed :(

Comment: Yes, I see what is going on there: The `TracingChannelInterceptor` does build for us a fully new message, based on a failed message. I'll see what we can fix over there. Meanwhile you can disable it altogether `spring.sleuth.integration.enabled=false`. Or don't trace that error channel: `spring.sleuth.integration.patterns=!appErrorChannel`

Comment: Thanks, settled for `spring.sleuth.integration.patterns=!appErrorChannel`