# Spring Integration MessagingException itself casting to String

Tags: spring-integration

Started seeing this behavior wherein the exception received via a `QueueChannel` configured as application's custom `errorChannel` casts the `Message` payload as `String` anywhere in the DSL except for the initial `.log`. Please help understand why is this behavior? Usage is with `WebFlux.inboundGateway` on **Spring Boot 2.7.13**

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(appErrorChannel())
                    .<MessagingException> log(ERROR, m -> "Appln Exception: " + m.getPayload()) // fine here
                    // error response
                    .transform(Message.class, m -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(constructResponse())
                                                                .copyHeaders(((MessagingException) m.getPayload()).getFailedMessage().getHeaders()) // class cast exception
                                                                .build())
```

Comment: I think eve your `log()` received that payload as a `String`. It is not clear why yet: probably you have some other interceptor on that channel which performs `toString()` on the payload. Or something else. You can do a DEBUG logging level on the `org.springframework.integration` to see how your message travels and what is going on with its payload. Some simple project to let us to reproduce on our side would be great, too.

Comment: Sorry, this is the same behavior we have reported in the past as well and you have already gave us a workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75109345/spring-integration-webflux-inboundgateway-replychannel-for-error-response

Comment: Any plan for a permanent fix, please?

Comment: The fix is like migrate away from Sleuth to Micrometer Observation: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/wiki/Migrating-to-new-1.10.0-Observation-API

Comment: I'm marking your question for closing since you don't mention Sleuth as a culprit.